# Why do C preprocessor macros work by simple textual substitution instead of function-like way?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

As title, I know that if I do like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define add(a,b) a+b

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", add(4,5)*3);
    return 0;
}
```

Then, due to C preprocessor macros's principle, textual substitution, the result is 4+5*3=19 instead of (4+5)*3=27.

If I want to obtain (4+5)*3=27, then the code need to be modified to:

```
#define add(a,b) (a+b)
```

However, what I'm curious about is:
why do C preprocessor macros work by textual substitution "4+5*3", instead treating it as a function "(4+5)*3"?

If C preprocessor macros work by function-like way, what issues or drawbacks would arise?

Comment: Because it was defined this way. There are other more sophisticated pre-processors, but they are not the part of the language.

Comment: Historical reasons: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/309389/what-is-the-origin-of-the-c-preprocessor

Comment: People made the current preprocessor do [weird and awesome things](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/AppendixA-AnIntroductiontoPreprocessorMetaprogramming.html). If you changed how it works now, some existing code would break.

Comment: While it was primarily intended for processing C code, it was designed to be independent. It was originally a separate application, whose text output was piped to the C compiler, so it couldn't interact directly with the C parse tree.

Comment: Short answer extracted from [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76093929#76094618): Because otherwise you  couldn't have [`va_arg`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/va_arg).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C was designed during an era of computing which, though it still seems rather recent and familiar to a few of us, was almost unrecognizably different from today's expectations.

In particular, there was a huge emphasis on *smallness* and *simplicity*.  The PDP-11, where C and Unix got their start, was a 16-bit machine, with a 64 kilobyte address space.  (That is, one tenth of the widely-mocked MS-DOS address space and the alleged line about "640k should be enough for anybody".)  Therefore, for a complicated program like a compiler, every feature had to really carry its weight.  The designers of C and Unix took it as a point of pride to make do with as little as they could.

Furthermore, C already had true functions that worked (by definition!) in a properly function-like way.  There was no compelling reason to give function-like preprocessor macros any kind of true-function semantics.  The rest of the preprocessor operated on pure textual substitution, so it was natural to use pure textual substitution on function-like macro arguments, too.  That worked well much of time, and the workarounds when it didn't (like, using extra parentheses) were obvious and easy enough to remember, and when they didn't work, well, in that case (as today) you should probably be writing a proper function anyway.

The syntax and semantics of the C preprocessor, though obviously rather different from "core C", were influenced by and similar to some of the other popular macro preprocessors of the day, such as [`m4`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M4_(computer_language)) and the macro processors built into [assemblers](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Assembler_(computing)).

It was also sometimes positively advantageous to have textual, as opposed to "proper", semantics for macro arguments.  Functions must take evaluatable expressions as arguments, but preprocessor macros can take type names, or bare operators.  For example, back when we had to cast `malloc`'s return value, I always used

```
#define Salloc(type) (type *)malloc(sizeof(type))
```

so I could then say things like

```
struct foo *fp = Salloc(struct foo);
```

I would also sometimes say

```
#define Compare(a, op, b) (cmpfunc(a, b) op 0)
```

where `cmpfunc` is a function returning negative, 0, or positive, if I wanted to be able to write

```
if(Compare(foo, <, goo))
```

See also [this good answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/309389/what-is-the-origin-of-the-c-preprocessor) someone found over on softwareengineering.stackexchange.com.

Disclaimer: I hasten to add that I would not recommend using either that `Salloc` or that `Compare` macro today!  But back in the day, we did things like that all the time, and it wasn't necessarily considered "preprocessor abuse".  And to this day there's one macro in the standard library that takes a type name: [`va_arg`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/va_arg).